# How can I replace values from one text file with other values from another text file only if certain values are equal?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file called `finalscores.txt` and I want to to create a python script which will open it and read in values from two separate columns.

This is my `finalscores.txt` file

```
     Atom nVa  predppm   avgppm    stdev    delta    QPred   QMulti   qTotal
  7.H2   2    7.674    7.853    0.000    0.000    0.968    1.000    0.993
  9.H2   2    7.434    7.458    0.000    0.001    0.996    1.000    0.999
 20.H2   1    7.602    7.898    0.000    0.000    0.945    1.000    0.982
 21.H2   1    7.959    8.113    0.000    0.000    0.972    1.000    0.991
 8.H1'   2    5.363    5.238    0.002    0.003    0.978    0.997    0.993
22.H1'   2    5.593    5.523    0.002    0.003    0.988    0.997    0.995
10.H1'   1    5.378    5.426    0.000    0.000    0.992    1.000    0.997
19.H1'   1    5.691    5.681    0.000    0.000    0.998    1.000    0.999
score: 0.9941270604681679
```

The values I want to take in are from the first, "Atom" column, and the fourth "avgppm" columns. I don't want to take in the first line:

`Atom nVa  predppm   avgppm    stdev    delta    QPred   QMulti   qTotal`

or the last line: 
`score: 0.9941270604681679`

I have another file called `pinkH1_ppm.txt` and I want to open it and append it. This is what my `pinkH1_ppm.txt` looks like:

```
2.H8 7.61004 0.3
1.H8 8.13712 0.3
3.H6 7.53261 0.3
4.H8 7.49932 0.3
5.H6 7.72158 0.3
7.H8 8.16859 0.3
6.H6 7.70272 0.3
9.H8 8.1053 0.3
8.H6 7.65014 0.3
10.H6 7.5231 0.3
11.H6 7.58213 0.3
12.H6 7.72805 0.3
13.H6 8.02977 0.3
14.H6 7.69624 0.3
15.H8 7.82994 0.3
17.H8 7.24899 0.3
18.H6 7.6439 0.3
20.H8 7.78512 0.3
19.H8 7.65501 0.3
22.H8 7.47677 0.3
23.H6 7.7306 0.3
24.H6 7.80104 0.3
25.H8 7.67295 0.3
26.H6 7.67463 0.3
27.H6 7.64807 0.3
1.H1' 5.8202 0.3
2.H1' 5.90291 0.3
4.H1' 5.74125 0.3
3.H1' 5.54935 0.3
6.H1' 5.54297 0.3
8.H1' 5.36287 0.3
11.H1' 5.50093 0.3
10.H1' 5.37814 0.3
14.H1' 5.96177 0.3
15.H1' 5.959 0.3
17.H1' 5.75214 0.3
19.H1' 5.69108 0.3
22.H1' 5.59257 0.3
24.H1' 5.55313 0.3
25.H1' 5.70819 0.3
27.H1' 5.74236 0.3
26.H1' 5.48061 0.3
```

I want to check if any values from the "Atom column" in my `finalscores.txt`, match any values in the first column of `pinkH1_ppm.txt` and if they do, I want to replace the second column in my `pinkH1_ppm.txt` with the value for that Atom from my `finalscores.txt` file.

So for example, in `finalscores.txt`, 19.H1' is the Atom which can also be found in `pinkH1_ppm.txt` so I would like to replace the value in the second column of `pinkH1_ppm.txt`, that also corresponds to 19.H1', which is 5.69108 with 5.681.

This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
import re 

filename = 'finalscore.txt'
ppmColor = 'pinkH1_ppm.txt'

df = pd.read_cv(filename,sep = " ", skiprows = 1)

col1 = df["Atom"]
col2 = df["avgppm"]

df2 = pd.read_cv(ppmColor,sep = " ", skiprows=0)
name = df2[0]
ppm = df2[1]
with open(ppmColor, "a") as ppmAppend:
    for line in ppmAppend
        if col1 == name:
```

I'm trying to use pandas. I'm very unsure about my second dataframe df2 because there is no header in the ppmColor file, I want to start reading it from the first line. I thought using pandas would be the best idea but I'm not sure how to approach this exactly.

Error: 
`replaceppm.py:10: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support skipfooter; you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.`

`df=pd.read_csv('finalscore.txt',sep=r'\s+',skipfooter=1)`

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File"replaceppm.py", line 18, in <module>`

`pink.set_index("Atom",inplace=True)`

`NameError: name 'pink' is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the two csvs into pandas `DataFrame` objects, then it is a matter of updating the second one with values from the first.  The [update](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas.DataFrame.update) method requires the two dataframes to have a similar index.

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                 

df = pd.read_csv('finalscores.csv', sep=r'\s+', engine='python', skipfooter=1)                                                                                                                   
df = df.ix[:, ['Atom', 'avgppm']]                                                                                                                                                   
pink = pd.read_csv('pinkH1_ppm.txt', sep=r'\s+', header=None, names=('Atom', 'avgppm', 'x'))                                                                                               

df.set_index('Atom', inplace=True)                                                                                                                                                  
pink.set_index('Atom', inplace=True)                                                                                                                                                
pink.update(df)
```

Comment: Once again, folks use `read_csv` for non-comma separated files. Use the general [`read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html). Likely csv is a wrapper to this method. And looking into *usecols* argument to avoid the `.ix` slicing line.

Comment: Actually, you can even remove the `set_index()` lines and use read_tables's `index_col=0` (indexing first column). So this is really a three-liner solution!