# Update a column based on matching columns between two dataframes (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file called pinkH1_ppm.txt which looks like this:

```
2.H8 7.61004 0.3
1.H8 8.13712 0.3
3.H6 7.53261 0.3
4.H8 7.49932 0.3
5.H6 7.72158 0.3
7.H8 8.16859 0.3
6.H6 7.70272 0.3
9.H8 8.1053 0.3
8.H6 7.65014 0.3
10.H6 7.5231 0.3
11.H6 7.58213 0.3
12.H6 7.72805 0.3
13.H6 8.02977 0.3
14.H6 7.69624 0.3
15.H8 7.82994 0.3
17.H8 7.24899 0.3
18.H6 7.6439 0.3
20.H8 7.78512 0.3
19.H8 7.65501 0.3
22.H8 7.47677 0.3
23.H6 7.7306 0.3
24.H6 7.80104 0.3
25.H8 7.67295 0.3
26.H6 7.67463 0.3
27.H6 7.64807 0.3
1.H1' 5.8202 0.3
2.H1' 5.90291 0.3
4.H1' 5.74125 0.3
3.H1' 5.54935 0.3
6.H1' 5.54297 0.3
8.H1' 5.238 0.3
11.H1' 5.50093 0.3
10.H1' 5.426 0.3
14.H1' 5.96177 0.3
15.H1' 5.959 0.3
17.H1' 5.75214 0.3
19.H1' 5.681 0.3
22.H1' 5.523 0.3
24.H1' 5.55313 0.3
25.H1' 5.70819 0.3
27.H1' 5.74236 0.3
26.H1' 5.48061 0.3
```

I have another file called pinkH2_ppm.txt which looks like this:

```
5.H8 7.72158 0.3
2.H8 7.70272 0.3
7.H8 8.16859 0.3
8.H6 7.65014 0.3
9.H8 8.1053 0.3
10.H6 7.5231 0.3
12.H6 7.72805 0.3
13.H6 8.02977 0.3
14.H6 7.69624 0.3
17.H8 7.24899 0.3
16.H8 8.27957 0.3
18.H6 7.6439 0.3
19.H8 7.65501 0.3
20.H8 7.78512 0.3
21.H8 8.06057 0.3
22.H8 7.47677 0.3
23.H6 7.7306 0.3
24.H6 7.80104 0.3
5.H2' 4.2621 0.3
7.H2' 4.54158 0.3
9.H2' 4.50708 0.3
12.H2' 3.76928 0.3
13.H2' 4.67514 0.3
16.H1' 4.52918 0.3
18.H2' 4.71109 0.3
20.H2' 4.63392 0.3
21.H2' 4.65975 0.3
23.H2' 4.27267 0.3
```

How can I check if the first column values of pinkH1_ppm.txt are equal to the first column values of pinkH2_ppm.txt and if they are equal, the replace the value of the second column in pinkH2_ppm.txt with the value of the second column in pinkH1_ppm.txt?

For example, the entry in first column and row of `pinkH1_ppm.txt` matches the the entry in the first column and second row of `pinkH2_ppm.txt`. Since the 2.H8 is the same, I want to replace 7.70272 from `pinkH2_ppm.txt` with 7.61004 from `pinkH1_ppm.txt`but I'm unsure on how to do it using the ix indexer in pandas.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
import re

filename = 'pinkH1_ppm.txt'
ppmColor = 'pinkH2_ppm.txt'


df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = r'\s+', header=None)
df=df.ix[:, [0,1]]
color = pd.read_csv(ppmColor, sep = r'\s+', header=None, names = ('Atom','ppm','x'))

df.set_index(0,inplace=True)
color.set_index('Atom',inplace=True)
color.update(df)

color.to_csv(ppmColor,sep=" ", header = False)
```

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007383/compare-two-different-files-line-by-line-in-python) post will shed some light on the issue

Comment: @FussinHussin thanks but is there a way to do this using pandas?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I want to read in from my file `pinkH1_ppm.txt` and see if any values from the first column match the values in the first column of my second file `pinkH2_ppm.txt` and if it does, then I want to replace the second column value from `pinkH2_ppm.txt` with the second column value from `pinkH1_ppm.txt` for the value that is the same in the first column

Comment: @user8358234 What is `x`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it should be the third column right?

Comment: Why are you duplicating your same question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45554860/1422451) (with accepted answer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45578783/1422451) (4 hours ago)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filename = 'pinkH1_ppm.txt'
ppmColor = 'pinkH2_ppm.txt'

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = r'\s+', header=None, names=('Atom','ppm', 'x'))
color = pd.read_csv(ppmColor, sep = r'\s+', header=None, names=('Atom','ppm', 'x')) 

color = pd.merge(color, df.loc[:, ['Atom','ppm']], how='left', on='Atom')
```

After merge since there are two columns with the same name 'ppm' they are changed to 'ppm_x' and 'ppm_y'

```
l = color[~color.loc[:,'ppm_y'].isnull()].index.tolist()
color.loc[l,'ppm_x'] = color.loc[l,'ppm_y']
color.drop('ppm_y',axis =1,inplace=True)
color.rename(index=str,columns={"ppm_x": "ppm"})
```